# Visual QuartzCore iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, quartz-core

Just a simple question.

There is a simple visual tool to generate source code for iOS/QuartzCore?

For example, i would make a CAKeyframeAnimation with a path and a (Ex. CGPathMoveToPoint and CGPathAddCurveToPoint), there is a visual tool to export source code?

I didn't find anything and i have written this:

[image: First Screenshot]

And it exports my source code like this:

```
CGPoint startControllerPoint = {219.5, 162.5};
CGPoint endControllerPoint = {118, 382};

CGPoint startPosition = {55, 161.5};
CGPoint endPosition = {273.5, 383.5};
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, startPosition.x, startPosition.y);
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(path, NULL, startPosition.x + (164), startPosition.y + (1), endPosition.x + (-156), endPosition.y + (-2), endPosition.x, endPosition.y);
CGPathRelease(path);
```

but isn't complete.

I wouldn't reinvent the wheel.

Thanks, sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a tool to draw and animate for iOS. [PaintCode](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/) and [Opacity](http://likethought.com/opacity/) lets you draw and export code, but not animate. [Quartz Composer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/QuartzComposerUserGuide/qc_intro/qc_intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005381-CH201-TPXREF101) creates complex compositions but it's for OS X, not iOS.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely have a look at [PaintCode](http://www.paintcodeapp.com). It has a sophisticated vector editor, and generates Objective-C source code.  It supports both Mac and IOS targets.  There is a free demo available so you can try before you buy. Looks very impressive.  The only thing is that I don't think it currently supports animations.

Comment: PaintCode is impressive but my aim is to create a path by specifying only the start point, others coords are relative, so as to be easily applied to animations. Thanks guys.

Comment: So just use PaintCode to define a Bezier path. But instead of rendering it as a path, change the code to use it to specify the animation path.

Comment: I know, but is an annoying thing to do for complicated paths